# Android - Making Properties mandatory Based on Type

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I am using kotlin for  android development, I have a data class say for example `Vehicle` and there will be three field `vehicleType`, `MotorCycle`, and `Bus`, when i set the `vehicleType` as `twoWheeler` it should show `MotorCycle` as mandatory and when i set `Bus` as a `vehicleType` at the compile time it should show me `Bus` field as mandatory(like annotations)
**Example**

```
data class Vehicle(val type : vehicleType, val motorCycle : Any, val bus : Any ){

    companion object{
      const val TWO_WHEEL = 0
      const val FOUR_WHEEL = 1
  }

}
```

If i create a data class `Vehicle` for type `TWO_WHEEL` it should show me `motorCycle` as mandatory at compile time
Is there is any custom solution for this ?
Any help

Comment: I think what you're looking for is `sealed class`es, or a private constructor with two static factory functions in the companion object, while making `motorCycle` and `bus` nullable fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sealed class Vehicle
data class TwoWheel(val motorCycle: Any) : Vehicle()
data class FourWheel(val bus: Any) : Vehicle()
```

Comment: I see what you're doing, but his Vehicle class has more than 0 parameters, you may want to have the TwoWheel and FourWheel classes pass in the type and the objects they were instantiated with as well.

Comment: all parameters to Vehicule must be the same for all subclass, if you need custom you can add to the subclass as needed... For the type, no need to pass it to vehicle, you can use the subclass type...  so you haven't to manager mandatory/optional parameters, all parameters are mandatory and scoped by type.